# PicklingError PyCharm while running in Python console

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am new to multi-processing in Python. I started with the simplest example I could find and still cannot run it!

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x * x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(5) as p:
        print(p.map(f, [1, 2, 3]))
```

I get the following error:

```
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function f at 0x7fa965ae68b0>: attribute lookup f on __main__ failed
```

I'd appreciate any help or hints.

Comment: are you using pycharm? https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-52857/multiprocessing-in-PyCharm-results-in-pickle.PicklingError

Comment: Yes! I am using PyCharm

Comment: @hmd.pouya: As a rule, *never* run `multiprocessing` code interactively (meaning from an interactive interpreter), or from an IDE. It's *very* environment-sensitive, and really expects to be run as a stand-alone script.